# Set size to icon in NavigationButton on Android

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

In a Nativescript/Angular app I have the avatar of the user on the left in the header. For Android, I have to use NavigationButton:

```
<NavigationButton #navigationButton *ngIf="isAndroid" [loaded]="navigationButtonLoaded()" [icon]="customImage" (tap)="toggleSideDrawer()">
</NavigationButton>
```

The customImage is a https resource; NavigationButton wants a local resource, so when the user signin I download the image, using the local resource. It works, but the image is big so it fills the whole header. I tried to simply ad a class con NavigationButton setting width and height but it doesn't work. So I added the loaded function, where I tried to set it manually, it doesn't give any error but it doesn't work:

```
....

@ViewChild('navigationButton') navigationButton: NavigationButton;
 ....

navigationButtonLoaded() {
    if (this.navigationButton) {
        this.navigationButton.effectiveWidth = 45;
        this.navigationButton.effectiveMinWidth = 45;
        this.navigationButton.effectiveHeight = 45;
        this.navigationButton.effectiveMinHeight = 45;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a custom Image within ActionItem to gain control over width / height.

Comment: With a custom image without NavigationButton it cannot be set on the left in the header in android, for this reason I have to use the NavigationButton component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to adjust the size of NavigationButton alone. You must use a [Custom Title View](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-a-custom-title-view), place an Image and align it on the left side to mimic the NavigationButton.